# Is it more secure encrypting 3 times with GPG?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, algorithm

Let's say we are using 3 different length passphrases and 3 different algos to encrypt sensitive data, e.g:

- `gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo CAMELLIA256 < input.zip > output1` (random 100 characters length passphrase)
- `gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 < output1 > output2` (random 150 characters length passphrase)
- `gpg --symmetric --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count 65011712 < output2 > output3`  (random 200 characters length passphrase)

Is this a much better solution than using only 2. step? Or just wasting time? Is this more vulnerable?

Comment: Have a look at [Combining multiple symmetric encryption algorithms - implications?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/combining-multiple-symmetric-encryption-algorithms-implications)

Comment: Bottom line: You're protecting against a threat that doesn't exists. Just like it doesn't matter whether you use a 50, 100 or 200 random character password to protect the keys.

Comment: What is optimal/good length for a gpg --symmetric passphrase?

Comment: @pothera That sounds like a decent *separate* question. Consider posting it as such (if it hasn't been asked and answered already).

Answer (score 6):

You may be surprised to learn the answer is "you are probably less secure."

Security isn't simply asking "can someone else hack my crypto?" Security is a big picture for protecting yourself and your data that includes three main attributes: *Confidentiality, Integrity*, and *Availability* (the CIA triangle.)  What your proposed solution does is it adds a lot of complexity.  A year from now when you try to remember all three pass phrases, and what order you have to decrypt them in, and did you get all the file types and options on the command lines correct, you might find yourself unable to get to your own data.  And because you're doing this on your own, you're not following a standard that other people use; this means you can't look up "how to effectively use three different forms of GPG encryption" and hope to find the right answer that works for you.

By creating such a complex, non-standard process, you are adding risk to the *availability* of your data.  This reduces your security.

Against this added risk, consider ways you can offset that risk with a gain in confidentiality.  Are you aware of any specific threats to GPG using AES-256?  (If you do know of something, don't use it at all!)  Are you aware of any specific threats against a 150 random character passphrase that would be offset by using a second algorithm with another 100 random characters of password? (For what it's worth, the rest of the world is unaware of any such flaws in GPG; if they were even surmised to exist, the code would have been patched.)

Your greatest risk is almost certainly not the cryptography.  Instead, most risks to security come from flaws in operational security (OpSec.)  Most importantly, you want to secure yourself against accidental releases of information.  Is the box secure and malware free?  Is it online?  Is the software and OS patched and current?  Did you download gpg from a reputable repo; did you confirm the hashes?  Did you compile the gpg binary from source yourself?  Did you use a cryptographically secure random number generator to create the 150 character password, or did you generate it using the output of random()?  How and where do you store the 150 random character password string - might you lose it?  Might someone else find it?  After encrypting the original data did you securely delete it, or did you just drop it in the recycle bin?

After taking these kinds of ordinary precautions, then you can consider the possible existence of external threat actors who could be highly motivated to deliberately steal your secrets (depending on their value).  Have you checked for a keylogger hidden in the cable or buried in your hardware?  Is there a camera observing the keyboard?  And are you re-checking all of your security measures every single time you enter the password?

If you don't understand the risks with crypto at a mathematical level, do not try to re-invent ways of stacking it together imagining you are improving security in some unknown way.  Instead, broaden your attention and make sure you are doing all of your security well.

Answer (score 1):

As with anything like this the answer is, what’s your risk/convience trade off? Are you a likely target? Are you going to find the ‘potential’ security benefit a pain to use? Using two algorithms protects against an exploit being discovered in one of them (if that day ever comes)... are you wanting to protect your content for many many years? It’s not always a yes or no answer, and this is an example of one. Each layer you add the complexity of use increases as does the potential security (albeit one that may be totally unnecessary)